# Update value in square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field which name is e.g:

```
nameVariants[0].texts[en_GB]
nameVariants[1].texts[nl_BE]
```

My code allows me to add dynamic fields by javascript, so I must update the index of the fields. But how to I target and update only the first bracket [0], [1] ... ?

I have tried to maintain the index this way, by replacing all the names with the index.

```
looping fields with index (idx)
$(this).attr("name", function() {
       var name = $(this).attr("name");
       name.replace(new RegExp('\\[\\d+\\]'), idx);
       return name;
});
```

But it does not seems to work. My dynamic field has the name nameVariants[].texts[en_GB], so it would also have to find empty square brackets.

Comment: What's the output you need...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign the `name` value, after replacing the idx

```
name = name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + idx + ']')
```

Ex:

```
$(this).attr("name", function() {
       var name = $(this).attr("name");
       return name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + idx + ']');
});
```

Comment: Yes , and the trick is **not** use `/g` !

Comment: @Cherniv also need to reassign the returned value

Comment: This seems to work. Is it possible to tweak so it will hit adn update nameVariants[].texts[en_GB] - where the index bracket is empty?

Comment: Try using `\d*` instead of `\d+`